# Cannot connect to Internet after update

Tags: 11.10, networking, internet-connection

I did a regular update of Ubuntu 11.10 yesterday night and it didn't require a restart.

After the update finished I still had connection (wired). But, today, when I tried to go to Google and other sites, there was no connection. Network manager is installed and it said `no connection found`. I've checked the cable and nothing seems to be wrong.

How can I get my connection back? It works fine on Windows (from which I'm writing this).

Comment: In my case, running an ifconfig only shows the lo0 interface up. when i had ubuntu 11.04 server, networking started automatically, i did the "upgrade" and now i only get the waiting additional 60 seconds for networking warning.... i have to login and get the sudo -i prompt in order to manually configure networking AND dhcp... I read it is a bug related to 11.10 upgrades that doesnt appears when you do a clean install. Seems that 11.10 is expecting the /var/run and /var/lock files to be in /run and /run/lock folder, but althought i did move the folders and created a simbolik -s link as describe

Answer (score 0):

This might seem stupid, but it worked in my case once:
Shut down, power off router, unplug the power cord of the tower and the router. Then wait for 1-2 minutes, plug it back in, power on.

Answer (score 0):

Is your IP address to your computer static or configured by DHCP?  Whats the contents of the file /etc/network/interfaces say?